# After Login into Admin Panel, Dashboard is blank

Tags: dashboard

I've installed new Wordpress on new domain, but now the Dashboard in not showing properly. Sometimes it shows, but not working properly as 'Add Media' button in post editor, visual editor is not loaded.

I tried debugging with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, and fix the errors, but still I face this problem.

[image: Now Show this]

Comment: What was the error? This is a fresh brand new up to date install with no plugins/themes? When you fixed the error were there new errors?

Comment: error was the "Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/khanq125/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 275" , after then no new error . and this is just Download fresh brand from wordpress.org , then install .

Comment: line 275 of `wp-includes/load.php` is where WP attempts to enable/disable error reporting based on the `WP_DEBUG` (and related) constants. try setting `WP_DEBUG` to false and enabling error reporting either via `php.ini` or by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your `wp-config.php` file

Comment: Now ,i got this error 
" Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/khanq125/public_html/wp-config.php on line 74

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/khanq125/public_html/wp-config.php:74) in /home/khanq125/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173"  also i set the define('WP_DEBUG', false); and add error_reporting(E_ALL); in wp-config.php

Comment: What does your hosting provider say about the `ini_set` issue? I suspect this is a hosting/server issue not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Your hosting provider has disabled ini_set().  Google it.  The solution is to create your own php.ini in the WP root directory and defining disable_functions in there.